# After installing jhipster JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory

Tags: java, classpath, jhipster

"I installed jhipster time but Java_Home is set to an invalid directory, How do I set up this jhipster?"

These are my system variable environment. I don't know what the problem is.

```
CLASSPATH:.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;
Java_Home:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin
Path:%JAVA_HOME%;%JAVA_HOME%\jre\bin%;
```

> Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
>   JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin"
>   Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
>   location of your Java installation.

Is there a way to  run **jhipster**?

Comment: Not related to JHipster.

Answer (score 2):

Your system environment variables are expecting the root directory of your JDK installation path.

**Notice**: `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar` and `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar` on your `$CLASSPATH`.

Try setting `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`.

Also, make sure `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\lib\dt.jar` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin` exist on your machine.

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't work. Do I need to reinstall the JDK?

Comment: @Archbishop was there a different error message than the one in your question when you tried setting `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just stopped working when CMD was installed.